# Const Char* name vs Const Char *name

Tags: c

Is there a difference between

```
const char* name = "name";
```

and

```
const char *name = "name";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no.

But there is a difference between

```
const char* name = "hello", something = "else";
```

which will not work, while

```
const char *name = "hello", *something = "else";
```

should

Comment: What is the difference between those can you explain?

Comment: const char* a = "hello", something = "else"; this declares a as a pointer to a char type, and something as a char. you can remedy this by doing a "typedef char* pchar" which will allow: pchar a="hello", something="else";

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference and both declarations are equivalent.

Note that C style tends to declare pointer objects this way:

```
T *a;
```

while C++ style tends to declare pointer objects this way:

```
T* a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Both are parsed as `const char (*name) = "name";` - the `*` is bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.

Declarations in C and C++ are based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.  If you have a pointer to some type `T`, and you want to access the value being pointed to, you deference the pointer:

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `T`, so the declaration of the pointer is

```
T *p;
```

In your case, `name` points to a `char` value which begins a string literal.  If we wanted to get to the character value `'n'`, we would write something like

```
const char start = *name; // assigns 'n' to start
```

Thus, the type of the *expression* `*name` is `const char`, so we typically write the declaration

```
const char *name;
```

Because of how C declaration syntax works, whitespace around the `*` token doesn't matter.  You could write it as

```
const char *name;
const char* name;
const       char          *                            name;
```

or some other combination.  I and many others prefer the first form, because it accurately reflects the declaration syntax.  There are others who prefer the second form, even though it presents a slightly misleading view of the syntax, because it emphasizes the type of `name`.

Anyone who claims to like the third form is either trolling or crazy.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly a matter of taste.

I personally use `const char* name` because I want to make it clear that the type is a pointer (a `char*`) but many people think that the more correct is use `const char *name` to show that `*name` is a pointer (to type `char`)